# CSS - Unable to center vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center vertically 4 divs present in a Bootstrap row.
Here is my basic code :

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3"><button type="button" style="float:right; height: 40px;">Contact</button></div>
     <div class="col-md-3">Activity 1</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">Activity 2</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">Activity 3</div>
</div>
```

So, I can't use Flexbox because I need to keep the button on the right of the row in medium screen and *justify-self:flex-end* is not enough to keep the button on the right of the row. I can't also move the row with the button at the end of the code, because I need to keep it in first for mobile devices.
I have also tried to use *display:table* and *display:table-cell* and it still not working.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: yes, you can use flexbox. put the row at the end of the code and reorder it with flexbox for mobile devices.

Comment: Problem is, when you`float` an element, you also take it out of the document flow, so centering it (horizontally or vertically) becomes impossible without a few dirty hacks. Provide a working example of the `flex-box` method you've already tried (and please remember to include all relevant framework libraries) - there could be a few solutions to explore that could keep the button right by unsetting `margin` rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** use flexbox and take advantage of the `order` property to push the first button to the right of the row, **then** flexbox can center the contents of each div.

At mobile size, you can override the order property with a media query.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-md-3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center; /* vertical center */

  }

.last {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 last"><button  type="button">Contact</button></div>
     <div class="col-md-3">Activity 1</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">Activity 2</div>
     <div class="col-md-3">Activity 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to display row as flex, remove the float right for your button.
The simplest way is to use `justify-content: space-between;` and set the button just before the `</row>`.
Then, use `align-items: center`.

Answer (score -1):

try with specifying class as below which helps to your solution.

```
.col-md-3 ~ .col-md-3
{display:table-cell;}
```